# HTML5 appcache in play! framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, html5-appcache

I am trying to use HTML5 application cache in play! framework to use my app for offline usage. But I am not finding steps to configure application cache manifest in play! framework. I am able to do this in apache tomcat. My requirement is , I will have few html pages with form fields which user should be able to see even play server is down.

Answer (score 0):

You should use common HTTP server as a reverse-proxy and... HTTP server than like described in the documentation: [Setting up front end HTTP server](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer)

It gives you opportunity to run more than one app on the machine at port 80, support for SSL, ability for serving static assets without Play app (that's what you need), load balancer, etc.